Is it possible for PHP to retrieve a Cookie on initial/first page load?
I am trying to retrieve, not set, a Cookie that exists for a certain site. The Cookie exists and was set during a prior session with an expiration date well into the future. It is not set with HttpOnly. It is set with path=/ and secure.
So, is it possible to be able to retrieve the cookie on future initial/first page loads? I am wondering how sites, like ecommerce sites, etc., know that I have items in my cart when I have not created an account, etc.
WHAT I TRIED
Endless Google Searches.
Reviews of Stack Overflows threads (they only address setcookie() and not how to retrieve a cookie on initial page load.
I have tried testing the existence of the cookie in PHP and if it does not exists I use Location: https://my.example.com/load-the-cookie.html where the request simply has a JavaScript that sends the request back to the server in hopes that, since I came to client-side, PHOP would somehow now know there are cookies available.
My Initial PHP Script (Note: I have an .htaccess directive that parses .html file against the PHP engine)
/**
 * Set the Timezone
 */
if( !isset( $_COOKIE['timezone'] ) && !isset( $_GET['reload'] ) ) {
  header( 'Location: https://my.example.com/load-the-cookie.html' );
  exit();
}
elseif( !isset( $_COOKIE['timezone'] ) ) {
  date_default_timezone_set( DEFAULT_TIMEZONE ); // set the server time zone to the app default
}
else {
  date_default_timezone_set( $_COOKIE['timezone'] ); // set the server time zone to user's local timezone
}

My Subsequent/Second Page Request
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script>
    //const ck = document.cookies;
    //alert("* "+ck+" *");
    window.location.href = "https://my.example.com";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

WHAT I EXPECT
I am trying to get a PHP script to retrieve an existing cookie on initial/first page load.
Before you close this question directing me to other SO threads that only seem to address setcookie(), can you simply respond with YES, this is possible or NO, this is not possible to do? Thanks...I'll continue to try to come up with some sort of way for a subsequent web session to continue on from where it left off on its last visit.
Or, at what stage in the client-to-server-to-client request process do cookies become available to PHP?
Cookies from DevTools Inspector

DevTools > Inspector > Network tab

SOLUTION/FINDING
Once I set the cookie expires date to the expected exact format in JavaScript, it started to work.
Deleted: const cookieExpires = new Date('2025-03-01');
Changed to: const cookieExpires = 'Sat, 1 Mar 2025 12:00:00 UTC';

$_COOKIE['timezone'] is how you access cookies in PHP. If it isn't in there, use your browser's inspector tools to see the cookies and also look at the headers being sent over.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php says "Any cookies sent to server from the client will automatically be included into a $_COOKIE auto-global array" . So we have to assume, if you can't get hold of it in PHP, that the cookie wasn't actually present when the browser made the request (or it didn't deem it eligible to send for some reason). Have you checked (using the browser tools)? We don't know what the cookie looks like, or its rules, or if/where it's held in your browser.

In order to avoid muddying the waters too much, is JavaScript relevant to your direct question? If not, I would recommend stripping that from the question, including tags, so as to not confuse people.

Chris, I did use / have used the devtools inspctor to see that the cookies exists and has existed. It is always there.

Even if there cookie is definitely there, various things can still mean the cookie isn't sent to the server. Without seeing the cookie's data we can't help you check any of them.

Chris, JavaScript was tagged simply because I was trying to use it in the reload process. I'll remove it to keep this cleaner.

Yes, ADyson...I have continually tested and checked that the cookies exist. I'll add a  picture of them to my OQ. Stay tuned...

Chrome has a really nice request inspector that includes cookie and even explains why certain cookies aren't sent. Open your inspector, switch to the Network tab and find your main document request and click it, and then switch to the Cookies sub-tab. There should be a checkbox "show filtered out request cookies". Any cookies not sent will include an info icon that you can hover over to get details.

Cool...I'll give that a try, Chris!

Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Once you've added an answer properly, you should also roll back the edit to the question. Thanks.

It is not clear what your problem is.
UNLESS the cookie is set with SameSite=strict, which will only send cookies from the domain and path it was set (so ONLY in 1a below), the browser will send the cookie on the ANY request if it has a cookie to send

User
a. clicks a link or the browers loads a resource on a page on the same domain and path the cookie was set.
b. clicks a link elsewhere that goes to the domain and path of the cookie
c. types, pastes, or drags a URL with the domain and path of the cookie into the browser
The browser looks in the cookie storage to see if there is a cookie for the domain and path and will add that cookie to any request to that path.
The server will receive this cookie in the $_COOKIE (in your case) and you can dump that to see it is there. Also you can look in the browser developer tools to see if the cookie is still there and matches the domain and path

So if the user ever allowed your site to set a cookie and it is not stale, you will get it on ALL subsequent requests from that browser to that domain and path.
Do note that you can install plugins and other security measures that will block the cookie or delete it on browser close. If the cookies are set as SESSION cookies, they will of course also be deleted when the browser closes.
Domains and subdomains
setcookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", $expires, "/", "my.example.com", true, true);

will set a cookie that is ONLY available to http(s)://my.example.com/ and pages there
setcookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", $expires, "/", ".my.example.com", true, true);

will set a cookie that is ALSO available to
http(s)://about.my.example.com/
http(s)://blogs.my.example.com/
IF you set the cookie on https://example.com/load-the-cookie.html  and the user loads https://www.example.com/, they will have the same issue if there is not a leading . in the domain

Also a cookie with SameSite=Strict will not be sent with the first request if you navigate to your application from another web page (for example, from webmail.com to my.example.com). Your browser tools (Network tab > Cookies) should tell you if that is the case.

Thanks Heiko. Nothing there tells me that cookies are being blocked. See my latest screenshot post to my OQ.

@mplungjan, my problem is that my PHP script does not recognize and read the $_COOKIE on initial/first page load. It eventuall reads the COOKIES on subsequent page loads.I just need the PHP script to handle existing cookies on initial/first page load...that's my problem :)

@dott I understand. It does not make sense unless your have  SameSite=strict

@dott IF you set the cookie on example.com and the user loads www.example.com, they will have the same issue if there is not a leading . in the domain - you may have an issue with your .htaccessince you mentioned that.

How do I find out if I have SameSite=Strict? Or how do I set my cookies to not have that attribute? If this is the case, should I set SameSite to "lax" or "none"?

@dott as mentioned by Chris Haas you can use the browser's network inspector to see what cookies are (and aren't) being sent in your request to the PHP script. This includes (at least in Chrome anyway) a column indicating the SameSite value for each cookie. e.g. here's a screenshot of cookies I've got when loading this very page we're using now, showing those values: https://imgur.com/JhigHn8. It also shows expiry date, domain, path etc. And, perhaps importantly for your case, there's a checkbox to get it to show you any related cookies which weren't sent

Thanks for elaborating @mplungjan. You used a very curious term in your explanation -- "subsequent". Subsequent is not my issue. My issue is initial/first page load...i.e., the first time the user comes back to the site after having closed their browser (while cookies are in place) - either today, tomorrow or in the future up until the date when I have set the cookie to expire.

Let me ask this question: does the latest version of the Safari browser on my iPhone 15 Pro behave differently than Chrome on my MacBook Desktop with respect to getting existing unexpired samesite=lax secure non-HttpOnly cookies on initial/first page load?

@dott why do you ask that? Are you experiencing different behaviour in those two cases? Are the cookies you've got stored on those browsers different in any way, from your observations?

@dott My issue is initial/first page load...i.e., the first time the user comes back to the site after having closed their browser...yeah we understood that. But you still haven't told us what you actually found when you inspected the cookies in the Network tool for that first request

Interesting find. I learned I can connect my iPhone to my MacBook via a USB charging cable (IDNKT). So, now I am going to troubleshoot the cookie issue on my mobile device to see what it tells me. The Chrome browser is still not behaving on first/initial page load. Now I am moving over to mobile to test.

@ADyson I actually did mention it and I shared a new screenshot of the network look at the cookies they are intact.

@dott, we're talking about my comment from an hour ago, where you said "cool". That is what we're interested in debugging and seeing.

@dott That's a screenshot of the Application area of the site. It tells you what cookies are resident on an already-loaded page. It's not the same thing. I'm talking about looking inside a specific request listed in the Network tool. Do this: open a blank tab in your browser. Then open the Developer Tools for that tab, and go to the Network area. In the new tab, load the URL of the page you're interested in - make sure it's for the first time in that session. The HTTP request to the page will then appear in the Network tool. Click on that request, and go to the Cookies tab inside that request

Wow, so very sorry to trouble everyone on this thread. After connecting my mobile device to my mac and inspecting the cookies I discovered the cookies were being set and updated as "Session' and not with an expiration date. I am posting my finding and revision up top in my OQ.

I learned a lot from this thread. Thank you everyone!
